# Wrong latex rendering in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

With python 2.7.12 (on Ubuntu 16.04), and matplotlib 1.5.2, the following code is rendered incorrectly:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
plot([1,2],[1,1])
xlabel(r"$\beta+1$")
title(r'$\alpha > \beta$')
show()
```

The xlabel renders as if it was `$\partial i\Delta$` and the title renders as if it was `$\rightharpoonup\Upsilon\partial$` as you can see here:
[image: output]

My latex installation is otherwise functional. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: You should describe what "incorrectly" means (what is expected behaviour and what is an actual one)

Comment: I think that it's pretty clear that the LaTeX rendering is incorrect in this case. That being said, on Mint with matplotlib 1.5.1 the result is correct (just to be sure; that means that e.g. "beta" is actually rendered as "beta" ;))

Comment: Works fine (Latex correctly renders) on macOS with Python 2.7.11 and Matplotlib 1.5.1.

Comment: Works fine on _Arch-Linux_ with `python 2.7.12` and `matplotlib 1.5.2`

Comment: The issue came from the rc parameters of matplotlib: for some reason, text.usetex was set to False in my matplotlibrc file. Putting it back to True solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [User's Guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html), about the `matplotlibrc` file:

```
# [...] When text.usetex is False,
# font.family may also be one or more concrete font names.
```

Therefore, you should use a concrete `font.family` property or just change the `text.usetex` parameter to `True` in the `matplotlibrc` file.

```
#text.usetex     : False  # use latex for all text handling. The following fonts
                          # are supported through the usual rc parameter settings:
                          # new century schoolbook, bookman, times, palatino,
                          # zapf chancery, charter, serif, sans-serif, helvetica,
                          # avant garde, courier, monospace, computer modern roman,
                          # computer modern sans serif, computer modern typewriter
                          # If another font is desired which can loaded using the
                          # LaTeX \usepackage command, please inquire at the
                          # matplotlib mailing list
```