# Pyplot LaTeX going wild in Python 3

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I have a very strange problem that appeared recently, more or less simultaneously to my Ubuntu upgrade to 16.10.

Using Pyplot, when I use LaTeX in labels, Python3 gives back something very strange. For example, I tried to compile the example from
http://matplotlib.org/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/text_demo_fontdict.html
and I got this result:

[image]

I try to upgrade my matplotlib with pip, but nothing changed. Right now:
numpy=1.11.1, matplotlib=1.5.3

Interestingly, this problem disappears when I go back to python2, and the conversion is good.

Edit: on another machine, with Ubuntu 16.10 up-to-date, the same mpl and np versions, this bug appears in python3 AND python2.

EEdit : I did not find the problem, but a guess is a problem in the cm font of matplotlib. I tried to change the font (see e.g. [How do I change the axis tick font in a matplotlib plot when rendering using Latex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322738/how-do-i-change-the-axis-tick-font-in-a-matplotlib-plot-when-rendering-using-lat)), and the problem disappeared...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Looks similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337229/wrong-latex-rendering-in-matplotlib problem. Do you get any errors / warnings while plotting?

Comment: Nothing that I am aware of. python -v does not give useful infos.

Comment: Works fine for me on `python 3.5.2` and `matplotlib 2.0.0b4` (MacOS). Maybe try updating matplotlib to 2.x?